# Bash script to configure the database for a drupal site install not working

Tags: drush, database, configuration

I have a bash script that I want to use to be able to configure a drupal site without having to go through the browser screens.

My setup is using XAMPP on MAC OS X with PHP

Directory for my files are `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zinco`

I've set up drush using composer.

The following command:

```
drush site-install standard --db-url='mysql://**phpmyadminusername**:**phpmyadminpassword**@127.0.0.1/**websitename**' --site-name=**websitename** --debug
```

Returns the errors:

```
Starting Drush preflight. [0.01 sec, 2.18 MB]                        [preflight]
Loading drushrc "/Users/chris/.drush/drushrc.php" into "home.drush"  [bootstrap]
scope. [0.01 sec, 2.18 MB]
Cache HIT cid: 7.1.0-commandfiles-0-db580a5f73406ff96a3c32b2bade2057     [debug]
[0.02 sec, 2.24 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.09 sec, 6.16 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 1. [0.09 sec, 6.16 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.09 sec, 6.52 MB]  [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.41 root directory at                               [notice]
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zinco/blah [0.1 sec, 6.52 MB]
Find command files for phase 1 (max=1) [0.1 sec, 4.58 MB]                [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 7.1.0-commandfiles-1-388d122ebce884666d6793a66ef4f7e2     [debug]
[0.1 sec, 4.58 MB]
Found command: site-install (commandfile=site_install) [0.1 sec, 4.58[bootstrap]
MB]
Calling hook drush_core_site_install_validate [0.14 sec, 6.55 MB]        [debug]
Returned from hook drush_core_site_install_validate [0.14 sec, 6.56      [debug]
MB]
Calling hook drush_core_pre_site_install [0.14 sec, 6.56 MB]             [debug]
Cache MISS cid: 7.1.0-alias-path--ba3c3f210d58349a27067f15d6ee74a3       [debug]
[0.15 sec, 6.67 MB]
sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.16 sec, 6.67 MB]                             [status]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/private/tmp/drush_rUKuqF --database=blah --host=127.0.0.1 --silent  < /private/tmp/drush_BtklU5 > /dev/null
You are about to CREATE the 'blah' database. Do you want to continue? (y/n): y
Sites directory                                                         [notice]
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zinco/blah/sites/default
already exists - proceeding. [9.69 sec, 6.67 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [9.69 sec, 6.68 MB]  [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [9.69 sec, 6.68 MB]    [notice]
Find command files for phase 2 (max=) [9.7 sec, 4.73 MB]                 [debug]
Cache MISS cid:                                                          [debug]
7.1.0-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [9.7 sec, 4.73
MB]
Cache HIT cid: 7.1.0-commandfiles-2-adcbc259623838c285e92ee0febd23c7     [debug]
[9.7 sec, 4.74 MB]
sql-query: SELECT 1; [9.7 sec, 4.74 MB]                              [status]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/private/tmp/drush_CHP0QP --database=blah --host=127.0.0.1 --silent  < /private/tmp/drush_LYzbtS > /dev/null
sql-query: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS blah; CREATE DATABASE blah        [status]
/*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */; [9.71 sec, 4.74 MB]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/private/tmp/drush_iWxNeP --database=information_schema --host=127.0.0.1 --silent  < /private/tmp/drush_8im4te
  sh: mysql: command not found
Returned from hook drush_core_pre_site_install [9.72 sec, 4.73 MB]       [debug]
Calling hook drush_core_site_install [9.72 sec, 4.74 MB]                 [debug]
Starting Drupal installation. This takes a while. Consider using the [ok]
--notify global option. [9.72 sec, 5.03 MB]
Calling install_drupal(Array) [9.72 sec, 5.03 MB]                        [debug]
exception 'Exception' with message 'Resolve all issues below to      [error]
continue the installation. For help configuring your database server,
see the <a
href="http://drupal.org/getting-started/install">installation
handbook</a>, or contact your hosting provider.<p
class="error">Failed to connect to your database server. The server
reports the following message: <em>SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
refused</em>.<ul><li>Is the database server running?</li><li>Does the
database exist, and have you entered the correct database
name?</li><li>Have you entered the correct username and
password?</li><li>Have you entered the correct database
hostname?</li></ul></p>' in
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zinco/blah/includes/install.core.inc:415
Stack trace:
#0
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zinco/blah/includes/install.core.inc(339):
install_run_task(Array, Array)
#1
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zinco/blah/includes/install.core.inc(77):
install_run_tasks(Array)
#2 /Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc(719):
install_drupal(Array)
#3 /Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/drush.inc(705):
drush_call_user_func_array('install_drupal', Array)
#4
/Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/site_install_7.inc(80):
drush_op('install_drupal', Array)
#5
/Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/site_install.drush.inc(289):
drush_core_site_install_version('standard', Array)
#6 [internal function]: drush_core_site_install('standard')
#7
/Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(359):
call_user_func_array('drush_core_site...', Array)
#8
/Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(210):
_drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#9 [internal function]: drush_command('standard')
#10
/Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(178):
call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#11
/Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(62):
drush_dispatch(Array)
#12 /Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(70):
Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#13 /Users/chris/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(11):
drush_main()
#14 {main} [9.93 sec, 11.64 MB]
Command dispatch complete [9.93 sec, 11.58 MB]                          [notice]
 Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec) 
 page   0.21       1      210.03
```

Can anyone advice me on how to get by this problem?

I'm not sure whether i'm putting in the right credentials to access mysql/phpmymadin, it's quite confusing. If someone could possibly walk me through them, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`sh: mysql: command not found`

Either mysql is not installed at all, or the `mysql` cli tool is not on your $PATH.

Comment: I've added export `PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"` to my bash_profile which I obtained from this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830108/1060051 could you expand to agree/disagree? Thanks

Comment: If your addition to the PATH allows Bash and Drush to find mysql, then I certainly agree. If Bash and Drush still cannot find mysql after you have modified your bash_profile, try sourcing it (`source ~/.bash_profile`) and try again. If that does not work, check to see whether or not there is a program called mysql in the location you selected. Regretfully, I cannot tell you what path your mysql tools were installed to, because I do not know.

Comment: Yes, that is all I need to know. If you append your answer with the information you've given me in the previous, I will mark it as the answer. Your comment has given me guidance to a solution. Thanks.

Comment: How to set the PATH is off-topic for Drupal answers.